# SQLite table constraint - unique on multiple columns

Tags: sqlite, unique-constraint, compound-key

I can find syntax "charts" on this on the SQLite website, but no examples and my code is crashing. I have other tables with unique constraints on a single column, but I want to add a constraint to the table on two columns.  This is what I have that is causing an SQLiteException with the message "syntax error".

```
CREATE TABLE name (column defs) 
UNIQUE (col_name1, col_name2) ON CONFLICT REPLACE
```

I'm doing this based on the following:

[table-constraint](http://www.sqlite.org/syntaxdiagrams.html#table-constraint)

To be clear, the documentation on the link I provided says that `CONTSTRAINT name` should come before my constraint definition.

Something that may lead to the solution though is that whatever follows my parenthesized column definitions is what the debugger complains about.

If I put

```
...last_column_name last_col_datatype) CONSTRAINT ...
```

the error is **near "CONSTRAINT": syntax error**

If I put

```
...last_column_name last_col_datatype) UNIQUE ...
```

the error is **near "UNIQUE": syntax error**

Comment: UNIQUE is missing a comma before it starts..

Answer (score 386, accepted):

Put the UNIQUE declaration within the column definition section; working example:

```
CREATE TABLE a (
    i INT,
    j INT,
    UNIQUE(i, j) ON CONFLICT REPLACE
);
```

Comment: Nice answer +1.
Does this create syntax allow me to use the regular insert method, and not the insertWithOnConflict with the SQLiteDatabase.CONFLICT_REPLACE flag?

Comment: I'm using `ON CONFLICT IGNORE` (haven't tried replace yet) with more than 2 columns, but I'm not seeing it honor the unique constraint, it just merrily adds the duplicates.

Comment: apparently because i have NULL columns, and that just shoots the unique check out the window

Comment: Beware using `ON CONFLICT REPLACE` it may not be what you want--it deletes pre-existing rows to allow the new row to be inserted. Normally, I would want to ABORT or ROLLBACK the constraint violation. [SQLite ON CONFLICT clause](https://sqlite.org/lang_conflict.html)

Comment: It seems that adding `UNIQUE(i, j)` to the create statement is completely ignored on android. It creates the table, but leaves off the UNIQUE constraint. I was only able to do this by using an index.

Comment: @gattsbr It seems? How did you find it to be ignored?

Comment: @LouisCAD I had found it to be ignored by adding the same data twice, i.e. not unique. If I remember correctly, it did work on ios. using an index instead worked on both however. Oleg's answer worked for me

Comment: sqlite treats all NULL values as different, so if your unique columns contain NULLs those rows might be duplicated.

Comment: @karmakaze: I agree but sometimes, e.g. if your table is used as a cache, you might want to use `ON CONFLICT REPLACE/IGNORE` depending on your cache policy. Ultimately, the main concern of a unique constraint is to *guarantee the row uniqueness*.

Answer (score 15):

If you already have a table and can't/don't want to recreate it for whatever reason, use [indexes](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_createindex.html):

```
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX my_index ON my_table(col_1, col_2);
```

Comment: This worked for me on android 10 since it seems that adding `UNIQUE(i, j)` to the create statement is completely ignored on android.

Answer (score 9):

Well, your syntax doesn't match the link you included, which specifies:

```
 CREATE TABLE name (column defs) 
    CONSTRAINT constraint_name    -- This is new
    UNIQUE (col_name1, col_name2) ON CONFLICT REPLACE
```

Comment: I initially did that...didn't work.  I tried it again just in case...still doesn't work

Comment: It should be 
`CREATE TABLE NAME (column defs..., CONSTRAINT constraint_name unique(col1, col2))`

Answer (score 2):

Be careful how you define the table for you will get different results on insert. Consider the following

```sql
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS t1 (id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, a TEXT UNIQUE, b TEXT);
INSERT INTO t1 (a, b) VALUES
    ('Alice', 'Some title'),
    ('Bob', 'Palindromic guy'),
    ('Charles', 'chucky cheese'),
    ('Alice', 'Some other title') 
    ON CONFLICT(a) DO UPDATE SET b=excluded.b;
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS t2 (id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, a TEXT UNIQUE, b TEXT, UNIQUE(a) ON CONFLICT REPLACE);
INSERT INTO t2 (a, b) VALUES
    ('Alice', 'Some title'),
    ('Bob', 'Palindromic guy'),
    ('Charles', 'chucky cheese'),
    ('Alice', 'Some other title');

$ sqlite3 test.sqlite
SQLite version 3.28.0 2019-04-16 19:49:53
Enter ".help" for usage hints.
sqlite> CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS t1 (id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, a TEXT UNIQUE, b TEXT);
sqlite> INSERT INTO t1 (a, b) VALUES
   ...>     ('Alice', 'Some title'),
   ...>     ('Bob', 'Palindromic guy'),
   ...>     ('Charles', 'chucky cheese'),
   ...>     ('Alice', 'Some other title') 
   ...>     ON CONFLICT(a) DO UPDATE SET b=excluded.b;
sqlite> CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS t2 (id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, a TEXT UNIQUE, b TEXT, UNIQUE(a) ON CONFLICT REPLACE);
sqlite> INSERT INTO t2 (a, b) VALUES
   ...>     ('Alice', 'Some title'),
   ...>     ('Bob', 'Palindromic guy'),
   ...>     ('Charles', 'chucky cheese'),
   ...>     ('Alice', 'Some other title');
sqlite> .mode col
sqlite> .headers on
sqlite> select * from t1;
id          a           b               
----------  ----------  ----------------
1           Alice       Some other title
2           Bob         Palindromic guy 
3           Charles     chucky cheese   
sqlite> select * from t2;
id          a           b              
----------  ----------  ---------------
2           Bob         Palindromic guy
3           Charles     chucky cheese  
4           Alice       Some other titl
sqlite>
```

While the insert/update effect is the same, the `id` changes based on the table definition type (see the second table where 'Alice' now has `id = 4`; the first table is doing more of what I expect it to do, keep the PRIMARY KEY the same). Be aware of this effect.

Answer (score 1):

it Works for me:

```
CREATE TABLE projects (
    _id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,
    project_type TEXT NOT NULL,
    name TEXT NOT NULL,
    description TEXT,
    last_updated DATETIME DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
    date_created DATETIME DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
    UNIQUE (project_type, name)
);
```