# SQLite - Any difference between table-constraint UNIQUE & column-constraint UNIQUE?

Tags: database, sqlite, android-sqlite

Question about SQLite.

In the CREATE TABLE SQL, we can add UNIQUE constraints in either way: column-constraint or table-constraint. My question is simple. Do they work differently?

The only difference I could find was, in table-constraint, there could be multiple `indexed-column`s in a single constraint.

Column-constraint:
[image]

Table-constraint:
[image]

Here is an example:

```
CREATE TABLE Example (
    _id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
    name TEXT UNIQUE ON CONFLICT REPLACE,
    score INTEGER
)
```

and

```
CREATE TABLE Example (
    _id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
    name TEXT,
    score INTEGER,
    UNIQUE (name) ON CONFLICT REPLACE
)
```

Are they different?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In this case there is no difference.

However, you could create an unique constraint on table, that would span over two different columns. Like this:

```
CREATE TABLE Example (
    _id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
    name TEXT,
    index INTEGER,
    score INTEGER,
    UNIQUE (name, index) ON CONFLICT REPLACE
)
```

Consult this post for further details:
[SQLite table constraint - unique on multiple columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2701877/sqlite-table-constraint-unique-on-multiple-columns)