# Create a UNIQUE constraint on two columns(Only if both exist in the database). If one of the columns is different, I don't want to constrain it

Tags: android, sqlite, android-sqlite

In the snippet below I have two columns with UNIQUE (MEMBER_NAME & KEY_CALORIES).  I only want it to be UNIQUE if both column are the same.  I am trying to get UNIQUE (MEMBER_NAME, KEY_CALORIES), or something on those lines.

Example of what I am trying to accomplish:
Perhaps the user enters a MEMBER_NAME(but that name is already in the databsae) but KEY_CALORIES is different I want to be able to add that item to the SQLite database. If the user enters an already existing MEMBER_NAME and KEY_CALORIES (only when they are both the same) I want it to be UNIQUE. If there is trouble understanding what I am trying to accomplish, I will update my question.

```
    // TABLE CREATION STATEMENT
private static final String CREATE_TABLE = "create table " + TABLE_MEMBER
        + "(" + MEMBER_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, "
        + MEMBER_NAME + " TEXT NOT NULL UNIQUE," + KEY_CALORIES
        + " INT NOT NULL UNIQUE);";
```

Comment: there is no KEY_NAME field in your given statement, is it supposed to be MEMBER_NAME?

Comment: Corrected my question thanks

Answer (score 2):

Using `UNIQUE(MEMBER_NAME)` constraint means that you can only insert a `MEMBER_NAME` once. What you want is a `UNIQUE` constraint on `MEMBER_KEY` and `KEY_CALORIES`.

You can use `UNIQUE(MEMBER_KEY,KEY_CALORIES)` as the constraint, which means that their combined values should be unique. Duplicates are allowed on both columns, as long as this combination is unique.

Possible duplicate / reference answer :
[Sqlite table constraint - unique on multiple columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2701877/sqlite-table-constraint-unique-on-multiple-columns?lq=1)

Comment: Can you help me implement that into the snippet I have provided in the question? I have tried implementing that and I cant get it to work without errors.

Comment: I have referenced the question earlier and I understand that but I am trying to implement that into my table statement but keep failing.

Comment: ?? Can you give me a hand?